# TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null ...style.display

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I have this error: typeError: document.getElementById(...) is null 
in this code, but the code works... (2nd line)

```
window.onload = function () {
document.getElementById('spinner').style.display = 'none';
var carousel = Carousel.carousel = document.getElementById('carousel'),
  images = carousel.getElementsByTagName('img'),
```

can you guess what is wrong?

Comment: Can you please share the associated HTML code?

Comment: You are trying to get an element that is not loaded yet !
I advice you to use the `onload Event` each time you need to get a DOM Element.
I am not sure if that what you asked about but, it would be better if you share your `HTML` script

Comment: The browser can't find any element with an id of "spinner"..

Comment: Probably he is adding the `#spinner Element` dynamically!
That's why I am asking him to share HTML code to see where is the problem.

Comment: @AdnaneAr—the OP **is** using the window load event.

Comment: @RobG if the script is loaded before the element tag it will not work even if he uses the `window.onload`